# Patch + Parametrize unittest Python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, parameterized-unit-test

I am trying to parametrize unit tests in Python using parameterize library and unittest framework. I need to patch certain functions and I use the following which works

```
@parameterized.expand([
    [a1, b1],
    [a2, b2]
])
@patch("package.module.f2")
@patch("package.module.f1")
def test_my_func(self, a, b, f1, f2):
    f1.return_value = "Hello"
    f2.return_value = "World"
```

However, the order of arguments in this working case is a bit weird. Generally while patching the arguments are passed from bottom to top. But when I use parameterize, along with patch, I had expected something like

```
@parameterized.expand([
    [a1, b1],
    [a2, b2]
])
@patch("package.module.f2")
@patch("package.module.f1")
def test_my_func(self, f1, f2, a, b):
    f1.return_value = "Hello"
    f2.return_value = "World"
```

but it doesn't work. Can somebody please explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/)

> **Using with @mock.patch**
>
> `parameterized` can be used with `mock.patch`, but the argument ordering can be confusing. The `@mock.patch(...)` decorator must come *below* the `@parameterized(...)`, and the mocked parameters must come *last*:
>
> ```
> @mock.patch("os.getpid")
> class TestOS(object):
>    @parameterized(...)
>    @mock.patch("os.fdopen")
>    @mock.patch("os.umask")
>    def test_method(self, param1, param2, ..., mock_umask, mock_fdopen, mock_getpid):
>        ...
> ```
>
> Note: the same holds true when using `@parameterized.expand`.

considering the documentation, your method parameters are out of order:

```
@parameterized.expand([
    [a1, b1],
    [a2, b2]
])
@patch("package.module.f2")
@patch("package.module.f1")
def test_my_func(self, a, b, f1, f2):
    f1.return_value = "Hello"
    f2.return_value = "World"
```